# Can Tridion 2011 SP1 Hotfix Rollup 1 work on CM without upgrading CD?

Tags: tridion

We recently upgraded (very successfully) to Tridion 2011 SP1.  I want to install Content Porter 2009 SP2 and it requires the Hotfix Rollup 1 to be applied.

The Hotfix Rollup 1 is divided into 3 parts:

- DB Script
- Content Manager
- Content Delivery

Is it possible to install the DB Script and Content Manager Hotfix but not the Content Delivery?  I ask because our rollout process for Content Delivery files is much more involved than for the Content Manager (and will therefore take more time).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The delivery side of HR1 provides around 10 fixes of which none look related to and changes in the way publishing is done. So, it would follow that you could update the CM without (yet) updating the CD.

However, to remain fully supported you should ensure that the gap in updates to the CM and CD is minimal and must be completed (often, this gets forgotten about). Issues that arise might not be supported unless support is in (advance) agreement with your upgrade process.

I would also advise you to do this first on the test or development environment to ensure that publishing and render on the CD side are working when CM is HR1 and CD is not.